# Any MS libraries offering Keccak-256 / SHA-3 (.net core)?

Tags: cryptography, .net-standard, keccak

Are there any MS libraries (.net core/standard) out there (currently research, beta or otherwise) offering Keccak / SHA-3 implementations ?

Answer (score 4):

See [Add support for SHA3 (Keccak)](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16485) on dotnet/corefx GitHub.

.NET has a strict policy of only using cryptographic algorithms provided by underlying platforms.

That said, there seem to be a few "unofficial" implementations [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22keccak%22).

Comment: I suppose I should have left out the 'implementations' word. The underlying providers seem to be offering things like EC and Keccak but .NET Standard does not yet offer it.